# equivalent connection for postgres and sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, postgresql

Is there an equivalent way to connect to a postgres database in a similar way that sqlite connects to a database using python?

For example, in sqlite, a connection will be defined by `conn = sqlite3.connect(curruser.dbname)`. What is the similar connection syntax for postgres?

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [psycopg](http://initd.org/psycopg/) connector then, and the connection syntax will be similar, except that you'll need to specify some more information in a connection string:

```
conn_string = "host='localhost' dbname='my_database' user='postgres' password='secret'"
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
```

Here are some examples: [Using psycopg2 with PostgreSQL](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Using_psycopg2_with_PostgreSQL)